# tensorboard shows no contents

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm having problem with tensorboard. My codes runs fine and when I tried to visualize the graph with  tensorboard --logdir = logs/log1   and then open the browser typing in localhost:6006   I saw the page with no content (only tensorboard sign and tabs like event, graph ...)
Help very much appreciated. No idea how to solve the problem. 
(i'm using jupyter notebook)

Here is the error messages I got:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory:       '/home/tiger/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-   packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/TAG' on path /home/tiger/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/TAG
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to read TensorBoard tag
Starting TensorBoard  on port 6006
(You can navigate to http://0.0.0.0:6006)
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2016 21:20:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
WARNING:tensorflow:IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tiger/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/lib/css/global.css' on path /home/tiger/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/lib/css/global.css
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2016 21:20:49] code 404, message Not Found
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2016 21:20:49] "GET /lib/css/global.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2016 21:20:50] "GET /external/lodash/lodash.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
.......
WARNING:tensorflow:IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tiger/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/favicon.ico' on path /home/tiger/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/favicon.ico
```

my codes are below:

```
n_features = x_train.shape[1]
n_samples = x_train.shape[0]
n_labels = 10
n_hidden = 200
epoch_train = 200
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 20

x_tr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_features), name='x')
y_tr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_labels), name='y')

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_features,n_hidden]),name='weight1')
b1 = tf.Variable (tf.zeros([n_hidden]), name='bias1')
w2 = tf.Variable (tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden, n_labels]),name ='weight2')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_labels]), name='bias2')

w1_hist = tf.histogram_summary('weight1', w1)
w2_hist = tf.histogram_summary('weight2', w2)
b1_hist = tf.histogram_summary('bias1', b1)
b2_hist = tf.histogram_summary('bias2', b2)
y_hist = tf.histogram_summary('y', y_tr)

with tf.name_scope('hidden') as scope:    
    z1 = tf.matmul(x_tr, w1)+b1
    a1 = tf.nn.relu (z1)

with tf.name_scope('output') as scope:    
    z2 = tf.matmul(a1, w2)+b2
    a2 = tf.nn.softmax (z2)

with tf.name_scope('cost') as scope:
    loss = tf.reduce_mean (tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(z2, y_tr))
    cost_summ = tf.scalar_summary ('cost', loss)

with tf.name_scope('train') as scope:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

def acc (pred, y):
     return (np.mean(np.argmax(pred, 1)==np.argmax(y,1)))


with tf.Session() as session:

session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

merged = tf.merge_summary([y_hist, w1_hist, w2_hist, b1_hist, b2_hist, cost_summ])
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter ('logs/log1', session.graph)

for epoch in range (epoch_train):

    offset = epoch*batch_size % (x_train.shape[0]-batch_size)
    x_tr_batch = x_train[offset:offset+batch_size, :]
    y_tr_batch = y_train[offset:offset+batch_size, :]
    feed_dict = {x_tr:x_tr_batch, y_tr:y_tr_batch}

    _, cost, prediction = session.run ([optimizer, loss, a2], feed_dict=feed_dict)

    summary = session.run (merged, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    writer.add_summary(summary,epoch)

    if epoch % 20 ==0:
        print ('training accuracy:', acc(prediction, y_tr_batch))
        print ('cost at epoch {} is:'.format(epoch), cost)
pred_ts = session.run (a2, feed_dict = {x_tr:x_test})
print ('test accuracy is:', acc(pred_ts, y_test))
```

Comment: In the above code: with tf.Session() as session: following lines are not indented

Looks like all lines until the end of for loop must be indented after that line

Answer (score 4):

You can access the tensorboard by writing the following command:
tensorboard --logdir="Your model temp directory" --host=127.0.0.1

Now open 127.0.0.1:6006 in your browser and you will have contents on the tensorboard.
I hope that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1421). Make sure you start tensorboard after running your program. And also see what other people did to solve it. It might be a bug in tensorboard. Do you want to build tensorflow from source?

Comment: Following one of the post at the link, I downloaded the global.css file and put it in the folder shown in the error message. Now the tensorboard is not totally blank.  It shows message like  ' no xxxx data was found ' . To me, it seems that tensor board cannot locate or read the event file. (I checked the log folder, the file is there)                                                                               I just installed tensorflow two weeks ago on my anaconda python3.5.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you get don't bother me. I guess the problem is that you wrote nothing. You can try adding this line `writer.flush()` after the line of  `add_summary()`.

Comment: just tried. same error                                                                                                WARNING:tensorflow:IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tiger/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/TAG' on path /home/tiger/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/TAG
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to read TensorBoard tag                                   I checked the folder. the event file is there.  so frustrating...

Comment: excuse me, could you paste the exact command you called tensorboard here? In your question, there seems 2 white spaces around the "=".

Comment: The errors you get happened to me before, and the results still showed, so I think they are harmless. And after upgraded to 0.8, the errors are gone. But is there any error message related to the path of logdir?

Comment: problem solved.  I removed the 2 white spaces around the '=' and then it works. although I still get error messages   thank you so much! sorry for late reply. just came back from vacation                                                                             thanks weitang!

Answer (score 0):

If you do see the tabs, but don't see the tab "embeddings", you might have an older version of tensorflow/tensorboard. Try upgrading to 1.0, this worked for me!